# How to loop through text fields and concatenate the result using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to write a javascript function that will loop through the input boxes and concatenates the text in each field together and displays the result in the result box. I tried multiple solutions and haven't been able to get any to work, I get that it needs an array of text fields but I can't seem to work it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form id="myform">
    <label for="text1">text1</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"><br>
    <label for="text2">text2</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"><br>
    <label for="text3">text3</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3"><br>
    <label for="text4">text4</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4"><br>
    <label for="text5">text5</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text5" name="text5"><br>
    <label for="text6">text6</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="text6" name="text6"><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Click This"><br>
    <label for="result">result</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="result" name="result">
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       var fields = [];
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter and map

NOTE: I gave the button an ID of "btn"

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const conc = [...document.querySelectorAll('#myform [id^=text]')] // id starts with text
    .filter(fld => fld.value.trim() !== "") // not empty
    .map(fld => fld.value) // store value
  document.getElementById('result').value = conc.join(","); // join with comma
})
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <label for="text1">text1</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"><br>
  <label for="text2">text2</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"><br>
  <label for="text3">text3</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3"><br>
  <label for="text4">text4</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4"><br>
  <label for="text5">text5</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text5" name="text5"><br>
  <label for="text6">text6</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text6" name="text6"><br>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click This"><br>
  <label for="result">result</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="result" name="result">
</form>
```

In one pass:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const res = [];
  [...document.querySelectorAll('#myform [id^=text]')]
    .forEach(fld => { const val = fld.value.trim(); if (val !== "") res.push(val) })
  document.getElementById('result').value = res.join(","); // join with comma
})
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <label for="text1">text1</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"><br>
  <label for="text2">text2</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"><br>
  <label for="text3">text3</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3"><br>
  <label for="text4">text4</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4"><br>
  <label for="text5">text5</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text5" name="text5"><br>
  <label for="text6">text6</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text6" name="text6"><br>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click This"><br>
  <label for="result">result</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="result" name="result">
</form>
```

Comment: when i use this i get the following error Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Sorry, I gave your button an ID

Comment: @CodeKid I made another version - I forgot that result is also a text field

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const data = document.querySelectorAll("#myform input[type='text'][id^=text]");
  //console.log(data);
  var fields = [];
  data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.value != '') {
      fields.push(item.value)
    }
  })

  document.getElementById("result").value = fields.join(",")
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <label for="text1">text1</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1"><br>
  <label for="text2">text2</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"><br>
  <label for="text3">text3</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3"><br>
  <label for="text4">text4</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4"><br>
  <label for="text5">text5</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text5" name="text5"><br>
  <label for="text6">text6</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="text6" name="text6"><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Click This"><br>
  <label for="result">result</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="result" name="result">
</form>
```

Comment: That is a really cumbersome way of mapping a form's inputs. Why not just [...data].forEach

Comment: hmm, Updated the code. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Do note that forEach does not work in early EDGE on html collections